# Toggle detach() selector in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three radio buttons, I want to detach a div when `input:radio[].val !== 'samplename'` .

THESE ARE MY RADIO BUTTONS

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input checked="check" type="radio" value="Invididual" name="type_of_membership" id="radio-indi"> <label class="default-link" for="radio-indi">Individual</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" value="Institution" name="type_of_membership" id="radio-ins"> <label class="default-link" for="radio-ins">Institution</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" value="Corporation" name="type_of_membership" id="radio-corp"> <label class="default-link" for="radio-corp">Corporation</label>
</div>
```

THIS IS MY CURRENT JS SCRIPT

```
var comapany_input = $("#company-div");

$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {

    if (!$('input:radio').is(':checked').val() == "Corporation") {
        comapany_input.detach();


    } else {

        comapany_input.appendTo("body");
        comapany_input = null;
    }
});
```

Comment: `$('input:radio:checked').val()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
if($('input:radio:checked').val() != "Corporation") {
```

to get the value of the checked checkbox.

`if(!$('input:radio').is(':checked').val() == "Corporation") {` will throw an error since the `is` method will return a `boolean` value which does not have the `val` method.

```js
var comapany_input = $("#company-div");
$("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
  if (this.checked && this.value == 'Corporation') {
    comapany_input.appendTo('body');
  } else {
    comapany_input.detach();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input checked="check" type="radio" value="Invididual" name="type_of_membership" id="radio-indi">
  <label class="default-link" for="radio-indi">Individual</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="radio" value="Institution" name="type_of_membership" id="radio-ins">
  <label class="default-link" for="radio-ins">Institution</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="radio" value="Corporation" name="type_of_membership" id="radio-corp">
  <label class="default-link" for="radio-corp">Corporation</label>
</div>
<div id="company-div">company-div</div>
```

---

You could just hide/show the element instead like

```js
var comapany_input = $("#company-div");
$("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
  comapany_input.toggle(this.value == 'Corporation')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input checked="check" type="radio" value="Invididual" name="type_of_membership" id="radio-indi">
  <label class="default-link" for="radio-indi">Individual</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="radio" value="Institution" name="type_of_membership" id="radio-ins">
  <label class="default-link" for="radio-ins">Institution</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="radio" value="Corporation" name="type_of_membership" id="radio-corp">
  <label class="default-link" for="radio-corp">Corporation</label>
</div>
<div id="company-div">company-div</div>
```

Comment: I want to detach it cause I want to to be deleted from the DOM so my validation(if_empty[intput]) will not cause the submit event to stop.

Comment: @Jackskiee then use the first option, see the updated demo also